# MultiValueConverter Failing to Bind to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

HelloAll: I am attempting to create a User Control that needs a MultiValueConverter for Scaling a Canvas in my App:

It takes the

1. Canvas.ActualWidth
2. X Min of Engineering units
3. X Max of Eng Units

.

```
public class MultiValueScaleTransform : IMultiValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
           double numerator     = (double)values[0];
           double denominator   = (double)values[2] - (double)values[1];
           return numerator / denominator;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

This seems to work okay when I feed it numbers but when I bind my XAML to View Model problems occur:

Here is the error msg:

> Error  7   A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Path' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.  C:\Users\mwardell\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HalliburtonCallouts (12)\HalliburtonCallouts\HalliburtonCallouts\View\UserControls\WellViewUserCtrl.xaml    31  38  HalliburtonCallouts

```
 <UserControl x:Class="HalliburtonCallouts.View.UserControls.WellViewUserCtrl"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:HalliburtonCallouts.ViewModel.Converters"
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
                 x:Name="uc">
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <Converters:ColorToImageBrush x:Key="ColorToBrush"/>
            <Converters:ColorToBitmapBrush x:Key="ColorToImg"/>
            <Converters:ColorToBG x:Key="ColorToBG"/>
            <Converters:ColorToFG x:Key="ColorToFG"/>
            <Converters:MultiValueScaleTransform x:Key="ScaleTransform"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueBg" Color="#FFA9DCF1"/>
        </UserControl.Resources>
        <Border Background="Red">
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- I used these to make sure the bindings of the user control are working-->
                <TextBlock Text="OverallStartDepth"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OverallStartDepth}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="OverallEndDepth"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OverallEndDepth}"></TextBlock>
                <Canvas x:Name="WellCanvas"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" >
                 <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                   <ScaleTransform >
                            <ScaleTransform.ScaleX >
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ScaleTransform}">
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                <Binding Path="{Binding OverallStartDepth, FallbackValue=0.0}"/>
                                <Binding Path="{Binding OverallEndDepth,FallbackValue=100.0}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </ScaleTransform.ScaleX>

                    </ScaleTransform>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            </Canvas>
        </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </UserControl>
```

I have determined that `OverallEndDepth` and `OverallStartDepth` are Bindable. See the StackPanel first four items or so. Doesn't Bindability prove they are Dep Properties of Dep Objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't and won't bind the the `Path` properties of the Bindings in the MultiBinding. Instead, you just set them like in

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding OverallStartDepth}">
```

which is equivalent to

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OverallStartDepth}">
```

and also to

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="OverallStartDepth"/>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

So the MultiBinding should just be written like this:

```
<Canvas ... >
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>

        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ScaleTransform}">
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}"/>
            <Binding Path="OverallStartDepth" FallbackValue="0.0"/>
            <Binding Path="OverallEndDepth" FallbackValue="100.0"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
```

Also make sure that you remove

```
DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}"
```

from the Canvas

Comment: Thanks @Clemens I have no Intention of keeping the TextBlock for binding of the OveralEndDepth/StartDepth. They are double properties. When I implement as suggested I get a cast Error. Starting with  <Binding Path="ActualWidth"/>

Comment: So I am still stuck. Why are we upvoting on things that do not solve the issue. seems strange

Comment: `ActualWidth` is not a property of your view model, so you need to specify the source of the binding. See my edit.

Comment: That said, you probably don't want to pass the actual width to the converter at all. Scaling is done in relative units.

Comment: It looks like you believe that ActualWidth is coming from ViewModel. It is not it is coming from Canvas/Parent. The OverallEndDepth / Start are coming from VM.

Comment: Did you notice the edit? There's now a RelativeSource in the ActualWidth binding.

Comment: I had to unset as solved. The original error is solved but I only get the Fallback Value passed to the Converter. The bindings for the Textblock still work but the Value [1] and Value [2] come across as unset when i remove the fallback value.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, You cannot use `{Binding}`, instead you can get the element by its name and get the value from its text property.

```
<TextBlock Text="OverallStartDepth"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Name="OverallStartDepthTextBlock" Text="{Binding OverallStartDepth}"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="OverallEndDepth"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Name="OverallEndDepthTextBlock" Text="{Binding OverallEndDepth}"></TextBlock>
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ScaleTransform}">
    <Binding Path="ActualWidth"/>
    <Binding ElementName="OverallStartDepthTextBlock" Path="Text"/>
    <Binding ElementName="OverallEndDepthTextBlock" Path="Text"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

**Note:**
You can bind `OverallEndDepth` is value that is bindable to dependency property of any control.

e.g. `TextBlock.Text` is a Dependency property- [SourceCode](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBlock.cs,05b78a7b564afbdd)

> ```
>     /// <summary>
>     /// DependencyProperty for <see cref="Text" /> property.
>     /// </summary>
>     [CommonDependencyProperty]
>     public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
>             DependencyProperty.Register(
>                     "Text",
>                     typeof(string),
>                     typeof(TextBlock),
>                     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
>                             string.Empty,
>                             FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |
>                             FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
>                             new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextChanged),
>                             new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceText)));
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// The Text property defines the content (text) to be displayed.
>     /// </summary>
>     [Localizability(LocalizationCategory.Text)]
>     public string Text
>     {
>         get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
>         set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
>     }
> ```

But, Binding.Path is an ordinary property and cannot be bound, hence you are getting the above error- [SourceCode](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/R/09b16a18c3d55db0.html)

> ```
> /// <summary> The source path (for CLR bindings).</summary>
> public PropertyPath Path
> {
>     get { return _ppath; }
>     set
>     {
>         CheckSealed();
>
>         _ppath = value;
>         _attachedPropertiesInPath = -1;
>         ClearFlag(BindingFlags.PathGeneratedInternally);
>
>         if (_ppath != null && _ppath.StartsWithStaticProperty)
>         {
>             if (_sourceInUse == SourceProperties.None || _sourceInUse == SourceProperties.StaticSource ||
>                 FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.TargetsDesktop_V4_0) // (for compat - Dev11 738992)
>             {
>                 SourceReference = StaticSourceRef;
>             }
>             else
>                 throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.BindingConflict,  SourceProperties.StaticSource, _sourceInUse));>             }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: None of the above answers actually solved unless I am willing to bind to something that binds to the value.  Se reissued Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139592/not-duplicate-multibinding-wont-allow-me-so-far-to-bind-binding